# Calculate the inverse for $\arctan(x^2+1), x≥0$

Tags: trigonometry, inverse

I have no idea how to solve this problem.

Calculate the inverse for the function:

> $$f(x) = \arctan(x^2+1),\quad   x≥0 .$$

Also specify $D_{f^{-1}}$ and $V_{f^{-1}}$.

I would really appreciate your help

Comment: write $x = \arctan (y^2 + 1)$ and solve for $y$

Comment: I might guess $D$ means "domain".  But $V$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x)=y = \arctan(x^2+1), x≥0$$

$$\tan y =\tan( \arctan(x^2+1))=x^2+1$$

$$x^2=\tan y -1$$

$$x=\sqrt{\tan y-1}, \tan y\geq 1$$